# How to prevent my app from being supplemented by ads by unauthorized users?

Tags: android, android-security

Today I found my app on some web-site. I downloaded the apk, disassembled it and found out that it includes a huge list of permissions that I did not include into my app and has the advertisements which was also included by someone else. Is there anything I can do to prevent such thing?

P.S. I would just ignore it, but the thing is, some of my users are downloading the application from this website instead of Play Market. And when they're tired of seeing the ads, they **come to Play Market and give me 1-star reviews**, which really hurts the application's overall rating.

Comment: That's essentially piracy - you can send the website which is hosting your APK a takedown notice, if possible (under the DMCA), but there's not much else you can do. Your question isn't about programming though, so I'd think it's off-topic. (This has happened with my apps too, and I agree that it's not nice)

Comment: @JonasCz well, I thought that there're some programming-related solutions, such as using DexGuard instead of Proguard and so on. But yeah, thank you for your advice - I sent them a message.